# Border around a rotating image

Tags: c#, wpf

Basically I'm trying to do something whereby a WPF image is inside a WPF border, and periodically I rotate the image by changing the RotateTransform Angle property.

The problem is, when I rotate the image, the border doesn't rotate, or attempt to change to fit the new shape of the picture. I've tried setting it's Alignment properties to stretch, and even binding the height/width of the border to that of the image, but no luck. I suspect the problem is that, when I rotate the image, it doesn't actually change the height or width of the Image object, so of course the border doesn't know what to do.

Is there a better way to rotate the image that would allow the border to resize, or if not, how do I get the border to resize correctly, given that I'm changing the RotateTransform Angle.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of rotating the image (inside the border), rotate the border (around the image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the LayoutTransform instead of RenderTransform for this. If you try changing the angle of rotation you'll see the border changes size to accommodate it. (Think this is what you're asking? If you actually want the border to rotate then you can just rotate that instead of the image)

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="rotate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid Background="Blue" Width="80" Height="80">
                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="10"/>
                </Grid.LayoutTransform>                
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Wow that was a lot simpler than I expected! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTranform`.

`RenderTransform` only does a visual transformation of the control and is applied after measuring and arranging Controls. Therefore it doesn't affect the size seen by other controls.

`LayoutTransform` really affects the layout of the object. It's applied before measuring and arranging control, so the other control see a change in the size.

Caution: `LayoutTransform` is much slower and won't usually give a smooth animation.

```
<Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image Width="50" Height="50">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
</Border>
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting series of edits tailgating the answer by 'Andy' above.